# literature.bib problems

Tags: bibliographies, urls

I'm using a .bib file for my bibliography.
It worked just fine til now.

Now I wanted to add the following literature:

```
@MANUAL{MaschinellesLernenByFraunHofer,
    author = {Döbel, I. and Dr. Leis, M. and Vogelsang, M.M.},
    title = {Maschinelles Lernen. Eine Analyse zu Kompetenzen, Forschung und Anwendung},
    organization = {Fraunhofer-Gesellschaft zur Förderung der angewandten Forschung e.V.},
    year = {2018},
    month = {September},
    address = {https://www.bigdata-ai.fraunhofer.de/content/dam/bigdata/de/documents/Publikationen/Fraunhofer_Studie_ML_201809.pdf},
    keywords = {}
}
```

It creates this in the .bbl but with errors:

[image]

[image]

As far as I could figure this out it has to do with the link. If I remove the link, the error is gone. But I don't know why the link causes this and how to solve it. I mean, I cannot just change the link.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Off-topic: are you sure you want to include one of the authors' academic degree ("Dr") in the `author` field?

Comment: is that uncommen?

Comment: Speaking from my own experience and field of study (economics), I'd say it's *extremely uncommon* to list the authors' titles, be they academic degrees (Dr., Prof., ...) or other ("Sir", ...). I think this is also true of other fields. E.g., I've *never* seen works of Einstein, Heisenberg, or Feynman referenced in a way that mentions the authors' academic titles, say, "Professor Einstein", "Prof. Dr. Heisenberg", or "Prof. Feynman".

Answer (score 1):

The cause of the problem is the presence of underscore characters -- `_` -- in the URL string. As you probably know, `_` is "special" to TeX. To circumvent this problem, you need to load the `url` or, better still, the `xurl` package and encase the contents of the `address` field in a `\url` "wrapper":

```
address = {\url{https://www.bigdata-ai.fraunhofer.de/content/dam/bigdata/de/documents/Publikationen/Fraunhofer_Studie_ML_201809.pdf}},
```

Encasing URL strings in `\url` wrappers not only gets around the problem caused by the presence of TeX-special characters in the URL strings, it also enables free-format line breaking of URL strings, something that's usually highly desirable from a typographic standpoint.

Finally, in case you happen to use a bibliography style that's been programmed to know what to do with a field called `url`, you could also write

```
url = {https://www.bigdata-ai.fraunhofer.de/content/dam/bigdata/de/documents/Publikationen/Fraunhofer_Studie_ML_201809.pdf},
```

This would seem highly appropriate, as a URL string isn't really an "address" in the usual sense of the word.